# Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit, client hangs on selecting large number of "columns"

Tags: sql, oracle, centos

I have an oracle 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit install over CentOS 6.2 64bit and everything is working fine locally, but when I try to connect remotely throw sqlplus installed in my machine (windows 7) something is just not making any sense is happening I am able to select any table with no more than 50 columns unless I defined some columns.

`select * from v$session;` (sqlplus hangs)

`select username from v$session;` (sqlplus work)

Also I can not do desc command for tables with more than 50 column like v$session.

`desc v$session` (sqlplus hangs)

`desc all_users` (sqlplus work)

Any Idea?

Regards

Comment: What version of SQL*Plus have you got on the client?

Comment: Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 32Bit client, and by the way I just found that everything is working with 10G 32Bit client!!!